# markAsUntouched not clear the red line Angular template driven form

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

If I can use condition based required field validation:

```
([required]="test.test1")
```

getting text area is red color underline and I can try some solution code but not worked

````
ex: (this.formGroup?.setErrors(null);
        this.formValidate.valid;
        this.formValidate.untouched;) ```
````

And I have attached image link below

[image]

Comment: any one Please give the solution Thanks in advance...!!!

Answer (score 0):

In a template driven form  you use `<form #f="ngForm"`.

So you need get the form with ViewChild and use the property form of the NgForm to mark as untouched

I Imagine (I don't check) some similar

```
@ViewChild('f') myForm:NgForm

//in any where
this.myForm.form.markAsUntouched()
```

Remember that a mat-error by defect only show if is touched

Comment: `this.formValidate.form.markAsUntouched();
this.formValidate.form.markAsPristine();
this.formValidate.form.updateValueAndValidity();
console.log(this.formValidate.form); `
**but i am getting same issue values:
controls: {....}
errors: null
pristine: true
status: "INVALID"
statusChanges: EventEmitter_ {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
touched: true**